# Django model formsets- how do I create a mix of existing and pre-populated "new" entries

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

Lets say I am building a Reading List app.  Each reading list has a name, and a number of ReadingListBook objects that link back to a book.  Additionally, lets say that there are a number of users that have been given access to this reading list.  Each user, after reading the book, is to give the book a rating of 1-10.  See the following models:

```
#models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ReadingList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ReadingListBook(models.Model):
    reading_list = models.ForeignKey('ReadingList')
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book')

class ReadingListBookUserRating(models.Model):
    reading_list_book = models.ForeignKey('ReadingListBook')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    rating = models.IntegerField() #rating of 1-10
```

And the following ModelForm for a rating:

```
#forms.py
class RLBRatingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=ReadingListBookUserRating
        fields = ['reading_list_book', 'rating']
```

At any given time, a user may have created ratings for some, all, or none of the books in a given reading list.

My goal is to generate a formset, of multiple RLBRatingForms- one for each potentially rated book in a ReadingList.  For any book that the user HAS rated, their existing rating will be pre-populated.  For any book that they have not rated, the input field will be blank.  I know how to create a formset for the existing ratings, but I am unsure as to how I might add on forms for any books that have not yet been rated.

E.g.- if there are 3 books in a reading list, "Book A", "Book B" and "Book C", and the user has only rated Book A, I want my formset to look like:

```
Book A: <Users Rating>
Book B: <BLANK>
Book C: <BLANK>
```

Note:  It is necessary that un-rated books do NOT have a database entry.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the problem, I think you may be able to solve this just by using features of Django templates and writing a custom filter.

For example:

```
# yourapp/templatetags/filter.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def has_rated(user, book):
    # Logic to figure out if the book is rated or not
    if user_has_rated_book:
        return True
    return False
```

and then in the template:

```
<!-- yourapp/templates/yourtemplate.html -->

<!-- loop through the books, provided to the template -->
{% for book in reading_list %}
    {% if user|has_rated: book %}
        <!-- display rating -->
    {% else %}
        <!-- display form field -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is some more info about [writing custom filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/). I hope I'm not oversimplifying!